# How do I check variables of another object, and call its methods?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working with triggers in Unity3d. I have a reference to another object that enters the trigger, and if that object has a variable that is set to a value, then I want to call its own method.

Something along the lines of:

```
if(gameObject.hasAttribute('canDance') == true) 
{
    gameObject.dance();
}
```

What is the correct code to perform such an action?

Comment: Mike, you need to access the script, something like `YOURSCRIPT ys = theObject.getComponent<YOURSCRIPT>()` and later `if (ys.canDance) ys.dance()`.

Comment: I don't really understand what "YOURSCRIPT" is in my case. Do scripts have types?

Comment: Yes, if you use `c#`, the type is the name of the class, for example if you have a script something like: `class Dancer { bool canDance; void dance(){} }`, `Dancer` is the type, and you need `theObject.getComponent<Dancer>().dance();`

Comment: There are many ways to access other object's variables: http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Accessing_Other_Game_Objects.html

Comment: That's good, but there is another issue. Because not all objects will perform the same action on `dance()`, I cannot really attach the same script to all of them, and therefore the type will be different for all of them as well, I suppose. So how do I handle this, so that I can check for the variables and call the methods regardless of the script types?

Comment: The method `getComponent<Dancer>()` will return null if the object don't have a `Dancer` script, so you can use: `if (go.GetComponent<Dancer>() != null) print("It's a dancer");`

Comment: Right, I understand that part. But here's a more specific question. If I have multiple actions that might be performed, such as dance, sing, play or jump, there is no way of checking for just one variable and one method from my code, and that method to be different in every object so they can perform their different actions (the methods will only share the name)? But instead I absolutely have to check `if(dancer = theObject.getComponent<Dancer>()) {dancer.dance(); } else if(singer = theObject.getComponent<Singer>()) {singer.sing(); }` etc, for every different possible action in the whole game?

Comment: Or, dropping the dance analogy, what i want is something along the lines of `if(gameObject.canDoStuff()) { gameObject.doYourOwnStuff(); }`, and the gameObject's own stuff might be either dancing or singing or jumping; but from this line of code, that shouldn't matter (or even be known).

Comment: You can implement a interfaz `interface Actionable { bool canAct(); void act(); }`, make your `Dancer` class implement it, and later use `go.getComponents<Actionable>()` (see the `s`), and `foreach(var a in actionables) if (a.canAct()) a.act();`

Comment: If this don't work for you, Update your question to meet the current requirement, and I will be post a answers according.

Comment: In theory this is exactly what I want, I just can't seem to get it to work because it said it cannot implicitly convert `Interface` to `Component` so I cannot `GetComponent` my Actionable script anymore, and I cannot set the interface itself to inherit from `Component`. So I just need to get a grip around implementing interfaces in Unity. Too bad I can't accept a comment as a solution, I don't know if I should delete the question now or what?

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the script attached to the GameObject. I will assume you already found the GameObject and hold a reference to it named `myGameObject`. If you don't know how to find it, you can do this:

```
GameObject myGameObject = GameObject.Find("Name Of GameObject in Scene");
```

Now to grab the script you can do this:

```
ScriptName script = myGameObject.GetComponent<ScriptName>();
```

Then you can make calls to the functions inside the `ScriptName` class like this:

```
script.functionName();
```